# Add in drop down ability to existing navigation menu

Tags: html, css, navigationbar

I have an existing HTML menu which I need to add further navigation to. I have added in the extra `<ul>` and `<li>` tags which I believe are in the correct place. The problem that I am having is getting the further options to drop down below the "Types of Claims" Option.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
      <li><a href="index.php">HOME</a></li>
      <li><a href="injury-claim-calculator.php">INJURY CLAIM CALCULATOR</a></li>
      <li><a href="personal-injury-solicitors.php">WHO WE ARE</a></li>
      <li><a href="what-we-do.php">WHAT WE DO</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">TYPES OF CLAIMS</a>
      <ul>
          <li><a href="#">CLAIM 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">CLAIM 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">CLAIM 3</a></li>
      </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="contact.php">CONTACT US</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and here is the CSS code:

```
#nav ul li {
display: inline;
width: 100px;
}
#nav ul li a:link {
color: #F1F1F1;
float: left;
padding-right: 45px;
text-decoration: none;
}

#nav ul li a:visited {
color: #F1F1F1;
float: left;
padding-right: 45px;
text-decoration: none;
}

#nav ul li a:hover {
color: #FFF;
float: left;
padding-right: 45px;
text-decoration: underline;
}
#nav ul {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/hd3dE/ ( multiple levels http://codepen.io/aamirafridi/pen/phKif ) . Have a look at http://aamirafridi.com/css/pure-css-responsive-menu

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
#nav ul li ul {opacity:0;}
#nav ul li:hover ul {opacity;1;}
```

-or-

```
#nav ul li {display:relative;}
#nav ul li ul {display:absolute; top:-2000px;}
#nav ul li:hover ul {top:0;}
```

-or-

```
#nav ul li ul {width:150px; position:absolute; visibility:hidden; top:-2000px;}
#nav ul li:hover ul {visibility:visible;}
```

Basically, you need to tell the nested ul (unordered list) that it has 1 style for the parent li which makes it invisible, and another style for the parent li:hover which makes it visible somehow.  There are multiple ways of achieving this.

http://csswizardry.com/2011/02/creating-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the
 `#nav ul li ul {visibility:hidden;}` and 
`#nav ul li: hover ul {visibility:visible;}`